# Box after hover :after element

Tags: html, css

I faced an issue when I hover the :after element the box which should show up does not.

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div class="top_line_dropdown">
        <span class="logged_in_user">
            Admin@aaa.cc (Admin)

            <div class="top_line_dropdown_content">
                aaaa
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top_line_dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 22px;
}
.top_line_dropdown .logged_in_user {
  font-family: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #999;
}
.top_line_dropdown .logged_in_user:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: none;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.top_line_dropdown .logged_in_user .top_line_dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 50px;
}
.top_line_dropdown .logged_in_user:hover:after .top_line_dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}
```

When I change **:hover** instead of **:hover:after** the box below show up. Could not figure out where the problem could be.

You can see a live example here: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cpqberzc/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

It is simply because `:hover:after` is a pseudo element that is created by your CSS but it does NOT have the `.top_line_dropdown_content` element as a child. When you do `:hover`, it check if the element is hover, and if so, it will apply the style to its children. I'll give you an example. I will add the `::after` pseudo-element in this code to makes you understand.

```
<div class="top_line_dropdown">
    <span class="logged_in_user">
        Admin@aaa.cc (Admin)

        <div class="top_line_dropdown_content">
            aaaa
        </div>
        ::after
    </span>
</div>
```

In the above example, the ::after element is where your element would be placed.

Comment: So how to fix it ? :D Should I place top_line_dropdown_content in &:after sass?

Comment: To fix it, you have to apply the right selector. Keep the :hover section to make appear the box when you want it to. And then, to apply your :after style to the right element. I'm not sure what it is supposed to looks like in your application so its hard to give an exact solution. But it seems like you need to look at your selector in your CSS, and check tutorial on the :after and :before pseudo-element to make sure you understand how they works.

Comment: Hmm... I don't get it to be honest.

Comment: Explain me the behavior you need, I will explain to you. You want top_line_dropdown_content to appear when you are hover .logged_in_user is that's it?

Comment: When I hover .logged_in_user :after element. :after element has an arrow content in it.

Comment: So then your selector is this one: ->  .logged_in_user:hover:after{} and then you put the arrow as the content of your :after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107064/discussion-between-yann-chabot-and-user2204367).

Comment: When you switch hover with after it doesn't even become "hoverable"

Comment: You don't switch, you keep your hover statement, and you add another :hover:after statement (or &:after in your SASS)